# Proxy user/password setting in System Settings apparently ignored

Tags: password, keychain, system-settings, proxy

Using macOS Catalina 10.15.2, I observe the following behavior: I open `System Preferences`, `Network`, the network I am on (only tested Ethernet thus far), `Advanced`, `Proxies`, `Web Proxy (HTTP)`. I enable the proxy, enter the host, the port and set `Proxy server requires password`. I enter the username and password (verified using a Windows machine) and OK/apply the settings. Repeat for HTTPS. Now for the error: when I attempt to make a HTTP/S connection, I get the keychain popup asking me to enter the proxy authentication credentials. Why? Why does it not use the data entered centrally? Incidentally, it seems that every user has to enter the credentials individually. Is this intended behavior?

After entering the data in the keychain popup and allowing access to the item as usual, applications work as expeced. The proxy is squid using a basic authentication scheme (again, verified to be working using a separate machine).